# Rev Driver Hub gets Error when I try to push code to it

Tags: java, android-studio, robotics

The Driver Hub and Control Hub are synced, but when I try to push teleops to the Driver Hub it gives me these errors on the Driver Hub:

> Missing Files: Some Viewforia / TensorFlow dataset files are missing from the First/vision folder on the internal storage. Please check to make sure you copied them as per the setup instructions in the readme

> libVuforiaReal.so was not found. Please copy it to the First/vision folder on the internal storage.

The part that I am stuck on is that there is no `libVuforia.so` file in all of the code. This file is making the OpenRc app crash and unable to upload the Teleop. I already tried reinstalling the SDK and that did not fix the issue. Any help on how to get around this error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue for a while, but finally, I found a folder in the OpenRC-Turbo that includes all of the files required to be dynamically loaded into the Robot Controller.

So, just download this on your laptop and connect to the control hub to put it in it's folder named FIRST

[The folder in qeustion](https://github.com/OpenFTC/OpenRC-Turbo/tree/master/filesForDynamicLoad)